# How can I load res.render response into browser?

Tags: node.js

So I have written this `node.js` code, which works like this:
I have this server, which has one route, which is `/marketers`, and is rendered from an `ejs` view, and consists of one form and a list which is empty in the first load. The form has one input and one button, and the default behavior is disabled. This is the front end code:

```
    $('button').on('click', function(e){{
    e.preventDefault();
    let marketerid = $(this).siblings('input#marketerid').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/marketers',
        data: {marketer: marketerid.toString()},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data); //I can see the expected HTML here
        }
      });
    })
```

In the server I use `marketerid` to render a new page, which is essentially the same page, but now the list is populated by the results received by the server from another web service. Now the problem is, the new page gets rendered as it should and I can see the expected HTML in the browser console, but the browser doesn't load it, I have tried `location.reload()` and `document.write(data)` in the place of console.log(data), the former just loads the first page(without the list), and the the latter just appends the HTML to the current page, so the script malfunctions, any ideas?

This is my node code btw:

```
    const express = require('express);
    const request = require('request');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

    const app = express();

    app.get('/marketers', function (req, res) {
        res.render('marketers', {data: []});
    });
    app.post('/marketers', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
        let marketerid = req.body.marketer;
        request({
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            url:     someURL,
            body:    `hph=${marketerid}&resellerid=0`
            }, function (error, response, body) {
            let marketersList = JSON.parse(body);
            res.render('marketers', {data: marketersList});
        });
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you are on page A which has JS code with an AJAX request to post data to the marketers route. You are then using res.render to render a new EJS page.

Are you trying to send the user to a new URL and render the HTML of that page, or are you attempting to dynamically change content on the current page that makes the AJAX request?

Comment: @KaneHooper thx for the quick reply btw. well I am trying to load a new page with the new content in the same URL. I could do a work around by sending data instead of a rendered page and then use some frond-end script to inject the data in the first page. But I like the other approach better. Is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: @KaneHooper By the way, if I want to load the results in another EJS template, I still get the HTML but cannot load it into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually you don't replace the entire contents of the current page with all new HTML.  Usually, you get some subset of content via the ajax call and insert that into the existing page (perhaps replacing some piece of content in the existing page) using DOM manipulation APIs in the browser that let you modify the existing pieces of the current page.

Or, the button can take the user to a new page by either just making the button into an `<a>` link that will take the browser to a new page where your server will render the new content for that new route or you can programatically set `window.location` to a new URL and let the browser go to a new page (with new content) that way.

If you really want to replace the entire web page (not my recommended way of doing dynamic content), you could do this:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){{
    e.preventDefault();
    let marketerid = $(this).siblings('input#marketerid').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/marketers',
        data: {marketer: marketerid.toString()},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data); //I can see the expected HTML here
            document.open();
            document.write(data);
            document.close();
        }
      });
})
```

Comment: well I am getting convinced that my approach may not be the best approach to achieve my desired results, but I guess there may be a way to do it this way; I tried your approach, but `document.write(data)` seems to only replace the HTML, and the scripts wont run. for example in the news page, the form's behavior is changed to `GET`, as the `$('button').on('click', function(e){` was defined on the previous button, which is replaced alongside the rest of the page, so the next click on the button does not act as intended and adds some query string to the URL.

Comment: @ArashChM - That sounds like there's some problem/difference with the HTML/scripts that you've generated as `document.write(data)` works.  You really need a different/better solution.  The same URL isn't supposed to stand for different content at different times anyway.  You should either be loading a different URL or using a query parameter on a new URL that you load from scratch or just dynamically insert some new content in the page or something like that.  Rewriting the entire HTML of the page is probably not the correct design.